# Powershell bigint output differ from declared value

Tags: powershell, .net-core, biginteger, powershell-v6.0

I'm porting lesspass password manager to powershell, but I'm having trouble when implementing the [_consume_entropy() method](https://github.com/lesspass/lesspass/blob/024d7439114b3a6c92db6e66a743880510cc5e5c/cli/lesspass/password.py#L59-L64), especially the Python `divmod`.

#### Reproduce

```powershell
PS> [bigint]$EntropyAsInt = 99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478
PS> Write-Host $EntropyAsInt
99600400399777173995117538344184441997741701018199539534149245151907290284032
```

#### Difference

```diff
99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478
99600400399777173995117538344184441997741701018199539534149245151907290284032
                ^ start diverging he
```

#### Question

What's the matter here? Am I using the wrong type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478` is a `[Double]`...

```
PS> 99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478
9.96004003997772E+76
PS> (99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478).ToString("F0")
99600400399777200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
PS> (99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Double                                   System.ValueType
```

By the time it gets cast to `[BigInt]` the original value is already lost.  Starting with a `[String]` preserves it, though...

```
PS> [bigint]$EntropyAsInt = '99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478'
PS> $EntropyAsInt
99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478
```

See [Instantiating a BigInteger Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger#instantiating-a-biginteger-object) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the behavior, but cannot explain it. What I *can* do is offer you a work around. Define a variable as a `[bigint]`, then parse your number as a string referencing the previously created variable.

```
[bigint]$EntropyAsInt=0
[bigint]::TryParse('99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478',[ref]$EntropyAsInt)
```

You can then verify that `$EntropyAsInt` contains the number you previously specified.

Comment: sees the answer I got on slack

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joel on Powershell slack:

> The issue is that the bigint cast doesn't take effect until after the value is parsed. It will first be parsed as a double, which in where the imprecision occurs
>
> If you want it to retain the exact number, you need to put your literal in quotes to make it a string and have the cast itself do the parsing
>
> ```
> [bigint]$var = "12345342827266162738883736363"
> ```

Work fine

```
[bigint]$EntropyAsInt = "99600400399777174105034830393873797761817714609490038944205586760025858632478"
```